# Rust equivalent to Swift extension methods with equal generic parameter constraint?

Tags: rust, extension-methods, generic-constraints

In Swift, I can add method to a generic type with parameter equality constraint.

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    // Available only for `Optional<String>` type.
    func sample1() { ... }
}
```

How to do this in Rust?

---

### Update

This feature is called [Extensions with a Generic Where Clause](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID553).

I think this is basically same feature with Rust's `impl` with `where` clause without explicit trait.

```rust
trait OptionUtil {
    fn sample1(&self);
}

impl<T> OptionUtil for Option<T> where T:std::fmt::Debug {
    fn sample1(&self) {
        println!("{:#?}", self);
    }
}
```

Is equivalent (without explicit trait) to

```swift
extension Optional where Wrapped: DebugDescription {
    func sample1() {
        print("\(self)")
    }
}
```

Therefore, I thought this Rust code would work, but it doesn't work with an error. (`equality constraints are not yet supported in where clauses (see #20041)`)

```rust
impl<T> OptionUtil for Option<T> where T == String {
    fn sample1(&self) {
        println!("{:#?}", self);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html and https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html

Comment: @Stargateur I think `PartialEq`/`Eq` trait is equivalent to `Equatable` protocol in Swift. Which is not what I am asking here.

Comment: oh so you want https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md ?

Comment: Does he? Is figured he just wanted `impl Foo for Option<String>` for some extension trait `Foo`. @Eonil, since not all of us are familiar with Swift, can you describe what this feature does?

Comment: @mcarton I think what you talked is what I was looking for. It works as I expected. Thanks. Can you convert your comment into an answer? I updated my question BTW.

Comment: @Stargateur I think it's something else though it looks like something highly related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just implement the trait for the concrete type `Option<String>`:

```rust
impl OptionUtil for Option<String> {
    fn sample1(self: &Self) {
        println!("{:#?}", self);
    }
}
```

I wrote crate, [type_eq](https://crates.io/crates/type_eq), which would let you write something that *looks* more like your Swift example. But it is identical to implementing the trait for `Option<String>`:

```
use type_eq::{Constrain, TypeEq};
use std::fmt::Debug;

trait OptionUtil {
    fn sample1(&self);
}

impl<T> OptionUtil for Option<T>
where
    Constrain: TypeEq<T, String>,
    T: Debug,
{
    fn sample1(&self) {
        println!("{:#?}", self);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = Some(String::from("hello"));
    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

There are actually very few cases where this crate is useful. Most of the time the simpler code above will work, and is preferred.